# What are some places where biofilms could develop?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, nutrition

I'm trying to think of places where a biofilm could develop other than on medical equipment or food processing equipment such as stainless steel mechanized blades or knives. I'm thinking more along the lines of biofilms on typical house hold things such as the bottoms of shower curtains

Comment: Biofilm is sort of an organized bacterial colony. It can develop anywhere and depends on the kind of bacteria involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thinking about places that are not very often cleaned and disinfected such as the toilet. Not only that, but the bottoms of shower curtains and in drains. Plaque on teeth is a biofilm, catheters, in/on wounds.

Answer (score 3):

They can certainly [develop in the toilet](http://www.biofilm.montana.edu/resources/pubs/98-025.html). Just try not to disinfect for a week...

Another place is the surface of living organisms, e.g. [dental plaque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_plaque) or the [leaves of a plant](http://www.open-access-biology.com/biofilms/biofilmsch12.pdf), etc...

Comment: They will develop if you disinfect or not. Most disinfection processes are not done by qualified people and are too short, use the wrong disinfectants or have other failures. And it is usually not necessary to disinfect your toilet - clean it, yes, disinfect it, no.

Comment: @Chris Disinfectants and/or cleaning reduce the number of microorganisms in the biofilm (by killing or washing out them). Without the systematic usage of these methods the biofilm will grow and will be much more obvious that it is there...

Comment: The problem with biofilms is that they withstand a lot of disinfectants. It is really much less of a problem than commonly thought.

Comment: @Chris In toilet maybe, by diseases biofilms are a serious problem e.g. by [Staphylococcus + Streptococcus biofilms](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC226988/).

Comment: I know. They are a serious problem in tubings in patients for example. And since it's a biofilm they are more resistant.

Answer (score 0):

biofilms also form in almost all systems with water flow (e.g. water tap, central heating), which also include environments outside of the household such as [rivers](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1574-6941.2003.tb01050.x/full) and the famous yellowstone park hot [springs](http://aem.asm.org/content/75/8/2464.short).